# Как выводить ленту постов в зависимости от ширины экрана?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть задача сделать ленту постов, которая будет динамически подстраиваться под ширину экрана пользователя. Сложность в том, что при достаточно больших разрешениях посты выводятся в 2 колонки, а при уменьшении разрешения - в одну.

Ленту в 2 колонки пробовал сделать поочередным добавлением `float` `left` и `right` в зависимости от четности элемента:

```
.post:nth-of-type(2n+1) {float: left; width: 50%;}
.post:nth-of-type(2n) {float: right; width: 50%;}
```

При уменьшении разрешения `media` убирает `float` и все идет в одну колонку.

Это решение рабочее, но у него есть существенный минус.В ленте периодически образуются разрывы из-за того, что посты имеют разную высоту и `float:left` может попасть вправо, а `float:right` может попасть влево.

Как можно нормально вывести ленту постов под эту задачу только средствами css?

Схематически то, что происходит сейчас:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А `bootstrap` не справляется с этой задачей?, мало того вопрос не полностью раскрыт, т.к не понятно что в вашем понимании в одну строчку и как это выглядит, не весь код блоков и данной ситуации, на ваш вопрос нереально дать ответ! Зачем вообще `float - right` использовать?

Comment: @Shnur там используется такое же решение, как у меня. проблема в том, что когда высота одной колонки превышает другую настолько, чтобы там мог влезть пост, то происходит разрыв.

Comment: Очень хотелось бы видеть поведение! Данной информации не достаточно, в HTML можно такие чудеса наверствать с CSS на пару, что потом сам черт ногу себе сломит, что по сути у вас и произошло.

Comment: @Shnur содержимое самих блоков приводить не стал, чтобы не загромождать вопрос. там обычные div-контейнеры, проблема в их компоновке. "Зачем вообще float - right использовать?" - если есть решение лучше - пишите)

Comment: Как я могу написать лучшее решение когда даже картинки вывода не видно, или вы думаете я мысли читать умею? Я не вижу то как у вас это реализовано, по сути CSS у вас написан правильно, но не понятно как у вас стоят блоки и как рисуется общая картина...

Comment: секунду, сейчас сделаю скриншот

Comment: Есть дизайн согласно которому вы делаете верстку, как можно понять что вы там сделали без него? по моему пониманию у вас идет лента справа и слева, а по центру контент и рвет все, что вы наверстали...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61460/discussion-between-shnur-and-dmitry-maslennikov).

Comment: добавил схематическое изображение того, что происходит сейчас.

Comment: После четного блока ставят clear:both;

Answer (score 0):

Для родителя

```
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between; /*Выравнивание элементов по в соответствии с основной осью, в контейнере*/
flex-wrap: wrap; /*Что бы переносилось на новую *строку* */
```

Для блоков уже

```css
marging: 10px ;/*для отсупов*/
max-width: 350px;
width: 50%;
```

Сам метод полностью рабочий и сам будет сбрасываться на новые строки